# Trying to write a query that displays the names of all authors that published papers in two consecutive years

Tags: sql, database

The database that maintains author and publication information has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Author (aid integer NOT NULL,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
affiliation varchar(50), primary key(aid));

CREATE TABLE Paper (pid  integer NOT NULL,
title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
year integer NOT NULL, primary key(pid));

CREATE TABLE Authored (aid integer references Author,
pid integer references Paper,
primary key(aid, pid), foreign key(aid) references Author(aid), foreign key(pid) references Paper(pid));

insert into Author(aid, name, affiliation) values (1, "A", "DS");
insert into Author(aid, name, affiliation) values (2, "B", "PS");
insert into Author(aid, name, affiliation) values (3, "C", "CS");

insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (100, "DS1", 2019);
insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (101, "PS1", 2019);
insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (102, "CS1", 2019);
insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (103, "DS2", 2020);
insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (104, "PS2", 2020);
insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (105, "CS2", 2019);
```

`Authored.aid` is a foreign key to `Author` and `Authored.pid` is a foreign key to `Paper`.

I'm trying to write a query that prints the name of all authors that published papers for two consecutive years. Here is what I have so far, but it seems overly complicated.

```
select au1.aid as id, a1.name as name
from authored au1 
inner join authored au2 on au1.aid = au2.aid
inner join author a1 on au1.aid = a1.aid
inner join paper p1 on au1.pid = p1.pid
inner join paper p2 on au2.pid = p2.pid
where p1.year = p2.year + 1
order by au1.aid;
```

Comment: I removed the DBMS tags. Only tag the one DBMS you're using.

Comment: _Exactly_ two consecutive years, or _at least_ two consecutive years?

Comment: Try to use **more descriptive** column names - `AuthorId` and `PaperId` are just **so much easier to understand** and grasp rather than `aid` and `pid` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `lag()`.  To get the author ids:

```
select p.aid
from (select a.aid, p.year,
             lag(p.year) over (partition by a.aid order by p.year) as prev_year
      from papers p join
           authored a
           on a.pid = p.pid
      group by a.aid, p.year
     ) p
where prev_year = year - 1
```

You can then use `in` or `join` or whatever to get the full author information:

```
select a.*
from authors a
where a.aid in (select a.aid
                from (select a.aid, p.year, 
                             lag(p.year) over (partition by a.aid order by p.year) as prev_year
                      from papers p join
                           authored a
                           on p.pid = a.pid
                      group by a.aid, p.year
                     ) p
                where prev_year = year - 1
               );
```

You actually don't need lag, but it is likely to be much more efficient.  An alternative is:

```
with pa as (
      select p.*, a.aid
      from papers p join
           authors a
           on p.pid = p.pid
     )
select a.*
from authors a
where a.aid in (select p.aid
                from pa p join
                     pa p_prev
                     on p_prev.aid = p.aid and
                        p_prev.year = p.year - 1
               );
```

Comment: I'm sorry this is something I should've mentioned, the tables are separate so we have to join them before we can do these operations. I've added the new schema.

Comment: P.aid is not a column in a paper table, when I try to run the last query on a MySQL server, it throws an error. Sorry if I didn't make it clear earlier.

Comment: @AchintyaKumar . . . The question was edited multiple times, but I clearly did not get the table layouts right.  I updated the answer, and still think it is simpler than any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it seems like gaps and island problem. Here is the small example [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3hBgExEVF6SdF8Q39kzCXa/0), which will give you an idea how to solve your problem.

```
select
    id,
    name
from
(
    select
        aid,
        name,
        count(*) over (partition by rnk) as total
    from
    (
        select 
            aid as id, 
            name,
            year - row_number() over (partition by aid, name order by year) as rnk
        from authored au            

        inner join author a
        on au.aid = a.aid

        inner join paper p
        on au.pid = p.pid
    ) val
) fin
where total = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that complicated

```
SELECT au1.aid as id, au1.name AS name
FROM author au1 INNER join authored authored1 ON au1.aid=authored1.aid
INNER join paper p1 ON authored1.pid=p1.pid
WHERE au1.aid IN (SELECT au2.aid FROM author au2 
                  INNER join authored authored2 ON au1.aid=authored2.aid
                  INNER join paper p2 ON au2.pid=p1.pid AND  p2.year = p1.year+1)
ORDER by au1.aid;
```

You can also use `SQL EXISTS` instead of `IN`