# Query to get the ID of authors who published papers in two consecutive years

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to write a query that displays the ID of the Author who published papers in two consecutive years. 
Here is the database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Author (aid integer NOT NULL,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
affiliation varchar(50), primary key(aid));

CREATE TABLE Paper (pid  integer NOT NULL,
title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
year integer NOT NULL, primary key(pid));

CREATE TABLE Authored (aid integer references Author,
pid integer references Paper,
primary key(aid, pid), foreign key(aid) references Author(aid), foreign key(pid) references Paper(pid));

insert into Author(aid, name, affiliation) values (1, "A", "DS");
insert into Author(aid, name, affiliation) values (2, "B", "PS");
insert into Author(aid, name, affiliation) values (3, "C", "CS");

insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (100, "DS1", 2019);
insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (101, "PS1", 2019);
insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (102, "CS1", 2019);
insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (103, "DS2", 2020);
insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (104, "PS2", 2020);
insert into Paper(pid, title, year) values (105, "CS2", 2019);
```

Authored.aid is a foreign key to Author and Authored.pid is a foreign key to Paper. And this is what I have so far but this is not giving me the desired result and I don't know what's wrong:

```
select au1.aid, a1.name
from authored au1 inner join authored au2 on au1.aid=au2.aid
    inner join author a1 on au1.aid=a1.aid
    inner join paper p1 on au1.pid=p1.pid
    inner join paper p2 on au2.pid=p2.pid
where p1.year = p2.year+1
order by au1.aid;
```

Comment: are you using `MySQL 8.0`?

Comment: @zealous I'm using MySQL 5.6, on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Could you please provide `insert` data for table `Authored`? and any particular reason are you using My SQL 5.6?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to write a query that displays the names of all authors that published papers in two consecutive years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61570032/trying-to-write-a-query-that-displays-the-names-of-all-authors-that-published-pa)

Comment: Why not share the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY au1.aid` to get distinct authors:

```
SELECT au1.aid, a1.name
FROM authored au1 INNER JOIN authored au2 ON au1.aid=au2.aid 
    INNER JOIN author a1 ON au1.aid=a1.aid
    INNER JOIN paper p1 ON au1.pid=p1.pid
    INNER JOIN paper p2 ON au2.pid=p2.pid AND p1.year+1 = p2.year
GROUP BY au1.aid
ORDER BY au1.aid
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your query but an IN clause looks to be useful:

```
    where paper.year IN ('2019', '2020')
```